# How make Word 2007 update all fields upon save

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

How do I make Word 2007 update all fields upon save? This should include fields in headers and footers.

If possible, no macros and VB code please. I want to keep the documents clean.

Comment: My memory is a little rusty, but I think `F9` or `Ctrl+F9` is involved. If you hit that before `Ctrl+S`, you should be fine.

Comment: `Ctrl+A` then `Ctrl+F9` doesn't include the headers and footers.

Comment: This question may be of interest: http://superuser.com/questions/51268/how-to-make-a-table-of-content-auto-update

Comment: Typically code wouldn't be stored in an actual production document, but rather a template or external assembly using COM / Office Interop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since Ctrl+A and Ctrl+F9 will not address the headers/footers, and possibly other stories, VBA or other code will be required, which would probably be a question best fit for Stack Overflow.

VBA code might look like:

```
Sub updateFieldsIncludeHeadersFooters()
    Dim sec As Section
    Dim hdrftr As HeaderFooter

    ActiveDocument.Fields.Update 'address the fields in the main text story

    'now go through headers/footers for each section, update fields per range
    For Each sec In ActiveDocument.Sections
        For Each hdrftr In sec.Headers
            hdrftr.Range.Fields.Update
        Next
        For Each hdrftr In sec.Footers
            hdrftr.Range.Fields.Update
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

I would not recommend taking over Word's Save event to run this automatically, but rather hooking it to a button or have some other way for the user to explicitly call it.